# Cannot install Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-oxygen, eclipse-photon

I downloaded the dmg file but on starting the installer, it stops with the following error:

ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000/content.xml.xz.
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:888)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'http://mirror.switch.ch/eclipse/releases/oxygen/201804111000/content.xml.xz'
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:176)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:220)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1085)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:516)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
... 1 more

Comment: You have tagged this Oxygen and Photon - which one are you trying to install (looks like Oxygen)? Photon is the current release.

Comment: try to look whether you can access the repo: curl -O http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000/content.xml.xz

Comment: Try downloading a package instead of the installer. The package would have everything you need.

Comment: @TonyWeddle, thanks this helped! :)

Comment: @mko, yes it was accessible, but somehow the installer could not access it. Downloading a package instead helped.

Comment: @greg-449, I had tried with both, the logs I pasted here are from the time I tried with oxygen. I wasn't having any luck with photon either, until I tried downloading the package instead of the installer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Photon installer on Fedora 28. I'm honestly not sure why I ever even use the installer anymore. :-\